# Saxon representation of XPath evalutions

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

In Apache Xalan and the .NET XSLT processor, XPath evaluations can be represented by a DTMNodeIterator and an XPathNodeIterator, respectively. Does Saxan have an equivalent to these?

Comment: Well, on the s9api level I would say `XdmSequenceIterator` http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/XdmSequenceIterator.html, as far as it is possible to speak of equivalences between the XSLT 1 based Xalan or XQuery 1 aimed but XPath 1 restricted .NET API and the XPath 2 and 3 and 3.1 XDM representation of Saxon 9.

Answer (score 1):

The design in Saxon is different, but there are many points of similarity.

In Saxon, at the system programming level, which most users will not need to concern themselves with, the `Expression` object has a method `Expression.iterate(context)` which returns a `SequenceIterator`. Because this is XPath 2.0/3.1 rather than 1.0, the `SequenceIterator` can return any items (nodes, atomic values, or functions), not just nodes. There are many internal implementations of `SequenceIterator`; one of the most important is `AxisIterator` which is always used for navigation of XDM trees, typically using the XPath axes.

At the s9api level, which is designed as an API for typical user applications, an executable XPath expression is represented by an `XPathSelector` object. This is an `Iterable` so you can use `for (Item item : selector)` syntax rather than using the iterator explicitly; if you do use the `iterator` method then it actually returns an `XdmSequenceIterator<XdmItem>` but for all practical purposes you can use this as a `java.util.Iterator<XdmItem>`, where an `XdmItem` is a node, atomic value, or function.

Saxon 9.9 also introduces a streams-based API which has similarities to Linq. This allows you to navigate a tree using Java functional interfaces: you can now write things like:

```
for (XdmNode pack : testInput.select(
            child("package").where(attributeEq("role", "secondary"))).asListOfNodes() {
           ...
}
```

which completely hides the underlying iterators. This is equivalent to iterating over the result of XPath expression `package[@role='secondary']`, but it saves the cost of compiling the expression, which is often much greater than the execution cost.

Comment: Thanks. At the moment we just try to migrate from Xalan, so XSLT 1.0 suffices (for now). How does the XpathSelector arise when using extension functions (in Java)?

Comment: If an extension function is doing that kind of navigation then usually with XSLT 2.0 it's best to make it a stylesheet function written in XSLT rather than an extension function written in Java. But there's masses of documentation on Saxon extension functions, and if you can't follow it you'll need to ask a much more specific question about what part you don't understand.

Comment: 1) The reason why we use extension functions is because we do geometry calculations which currently depend on the JTS library, so I do not think the XSLT functions suffices.
2) Furthermore we are doing a migration. So it would be nice to first make the migration from Xalan to Saxon and then afterwards make optimizations. Do you know how to make the XpathSelector arise as I asked?

Comment: Unfortunately there are very many ways of doing this, and which is best for you depends on many factors: which Saxon edition you're using, which API you are using, and so on. This is one that is probably best asked on the Saxon help forum at saxonica.plan.io which (unlike SO) allows an extended discussion.

Comment: I will look there, but if there are many ways, could you provide just one way? Right now we obtain a TinyElementImpl instead.

Comment: Please don't ask new questions in comments on an answer to your original question, unless they are simply requests to clarify the answer. Start a new question.